# How to properly ask for COARSE and FINE location permission using accompanist?

Tags: android, kotlin, jetpack-compose-accompanist

Accompanist allows to ask for one permission at once is it possible to ask for these two location permission at once?

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

That's my code

```kotlin
PermissionUtils.requestForPermission(
    context = context,
    permission = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    } else {
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
    },
)
```

```
@Composable
fun rememberPermissionLauncher(
    onGranted: () -> Unit,
    onDenied: () -> Unit,
): PermissionLauncher {
    return PermissionLauncher(
        rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
        ) { isGranted: Boolean ->
            if (isGranted) {
                onGranted()
            } else {
                onDenied()
            }
        }
    )
}

class PermissionLauncher(
    val launcher: ManagedActivityResultLauncher<String, Boolean>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, use `RequestMultiplePermissions()` instead of `RequestPermission()`. With this you can request multiple permissions at single time, and in callback you will get `Map<String, Boolean>` where permissions are keys and value is granted/denied `Boolean`.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun rememberPermissionLauncher(
    onGranted: () -> Unit,
    onDenied: () -> Unit,
): PermissionLauncher {
    return PermissionLauncher(
        rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()
        ) { map ->
            if (!map.containsValue(false)) {
                onGranted()
            } else {
                onDenied()
            }
        }
    )
}

class PermissionLauncher(
    val launcher: ManagedActivityResultLauncher<Array<String>, Map<String, Boolean>>
)
```

I am using `accompanist-permissions` version `0.28.0`.

Comment: Great Miroslav:) Nice dog! Thanks